# Dir-paginate GET row count after filter - angularJs

Tags: angularjs, filter, dirpagination

I would like to have the number of lines after filter on my list. 
With dir-paginate , the result is always 5 (== itemsPerPage) or i have > 5 lines.
Does anyone know how I can get this  row count for all page in my dir-paginate?

```html
<div>count filtered :  ({{ filtered.length }})</div>
<input type="text" class=" text-input form-control" ng-model="search.name"  placeholder="name">
<div class="col-md-6">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr dir-paginate="person in persons | filter:_this.search  | itemsPerPage:5  as filtered" pagination-id="excluded">
                    <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
</div>
<dir-pagination-controls max-size="5"
         direction-links="true"
         boundary-links="true" class="pagination">
</dir-pagination-controls>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to do this manually row count

change

```
 <tr dir-paginate="person in persons | filter:_this.search  | itemsPerPage:5  as filtered" pagination-id="excluded">
```

to

```
<tr dir-paginate="person in filtered = (persons | filter:_this.search)  | itemsPerPage:5 " pagination-id="excluded">
```

and you can get count by `filtered.length`

[Ref](https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/issues/102)